# hmac nsdictionary - express req.body

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, node.js, express

i am trying to do a generic - hmac verification with an iOS app and an express node.js app.

generating the hmac using given samples at: http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#js

having the following problem:
subclassed AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to gain access to `POST:`
i want to hmac the nsdictionary `parameters`.

so convert the nsdicionary to json - hmac it - and set hmac header in request.
on the receiver side, i use crypto-js and express to access the `req.body` - and hmac the json object.

problem is! - those keys are not in same order, even if i force the sort on the keys in nsdictionary, the transoformed json does not come in the order way.

after hours of googling i accepted that json objects cannot be orderd, in an reliable way.

so what is the best-practice to hmac an nsdictionary, by ignoring the order?
(i could hmac on only a few keys, but that would be way to less generic, mean adding a dictionary key would require code change in ios and express)

generating the hmac only based on the URI - works fine, but its a way to open :)

**UPDATE:**
to be a bit more specific.

on the app i transform my nsdictionary to json by  and then calculate the hmac of the json_string

```
NSDicationary * dic = @{@"key1", "value1",@"key2", "value2"} 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic
                                                       options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)    (prettyPrint ? NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted : 0)
                                                         error:&error];

NSString * json_str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

and i do a AFNetworking POST request calling passing my nsdictionary as `parameters`:

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:NSString *)URLString parameters:(id)parameters   success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

on the receiver app (node.js/express) i get the ctx.req.body containing the javascript object from the POST request -> but here it does not have the same order as in the json encoded string from the app (and i have not found a way to preserve order)

as i am not knowing what keys are in nsdictionary a static key-hmac would not work.

Comment: Do you send parameters as JSON object in request body or you create JSON object from request body at server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the JSON is just a string there is no ordering issue after it has been created. The point is to create the HMac value after converting the dictionary to a JSON string.

On the sender create the JSON representation and HMac the JSON. Send the HMAc result along with the JSON.

On the receiver HMac the received JSON and compare with the received HMac value.

The two HMacs should be equal.

Another option is to write a method on each side that examines each dictionary element key/item in the same predefined order and compose a string or data object from that. Then HMAC that result.

Comment: Instead of sending the NSDictionary as parameters send the JSON string as one parameter. Also updated the answer.

Comment: sending the app side generated json, as an additional POST parameter, and using this to generate hmac, did the trick :) - MANY THX